# how to have weekly dates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

How can we calculate the date for Monday in the past week. I am using asp and VB.net. Are there any date function. WE do have NOW in VB. But I want to know How we calculate the date for Monday in the past week. An example would like today is 1/31/2013 and the day is Thursday and I want the date for 1/21/2013 Monday. How will I do it

Comment: your question is not clear..what technologies are you used?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The obvious answer is "Look at a calendar, enter the Monday date of the week you're in in the first text box and the next Sunday into the second text box", but I'm guessing your question has something to do with doing this in code. It's very hard to answer, though, without knowing what language or platform you're working with. :-) Please edit your question, be more specific, and add the tags for those things. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I am using Vb to have the two dates in textbox controls in asp.net

Comment: Exactly I want to do it through code. I am using VB.net and asp.net

Comment: I am trying to use the Now object but I don't know how to subtract dates so that I get the date of the Monday of the previous week

Comment: Get a Significant Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but try this:

```
Public Function GetMondayLastWeek() As Date
    Return DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -Now.DayOfWeek + 1, Now.Date)
End Function
```

or this:

```
Public Function GetMondayLastWeek() As Date
    Return DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -Now.DayOfWeek + 8, Now.Date)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is giving me the date for the Monday this week. Is there any way I can obtain the date of Monday of the previous week.    1/21/2013

Comment: Try the second example, or maybe change it to -Now.DayOfWeek + 15